# Thread safety of simultaneous updates of a variable to the same value

Tags: performance, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Is the following construct thread-safe, assuming that the elements of foo are aligned and sized properly so that there is no word tearing?  If not, why not?

Note:  The code below is a toy example of what I want to do, not my actual real world scenario.  Obviously, there are better ways of coding the observable behavior in my example.

```
uint[] foo;
// Fill foo with data.

// In thread one:
for(uint i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
     if(foo[i] < SOME_NUMBER) {
         foo[i] = MAGIC_VAL;
     }
}

// In thread two:
for(uint i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
     if(foo[i] < SOME_OTHER_NUMBER) {
         foo[i] = MAGIC_VAL;
     }
}
```

This obviously looks unsafe at first glance, so I'll highlight why I think it could be safe:

1. The only two options are for an element of foo to be unchanged or to be set to MAGIC_VAL.
2. If thread two sees foo[i] in an intermediate state while it's being updated, only two things can happen:  The intermediate state is < `SOME_OTHER_NUMBER` or it's not.  If it is < `SOME_OTHER_NUMBER`, thread two will also try to set it to MAGIC_VAL.  If not, thread two will do nothing.

Edit:  Also, what if foo is a long or a double or something, so that updating it can't be done atomically?  You may still assume that alignment, etc. is such that updating one element of foo will not affect any other element.  Also, the whole point of multithreading in this case is performance, so any type of locking would defeat this.

Answer (score 4):

On a modern multicore processor your code is NOT threadsafe (at least in most languages) without a memory barrier.  Simply put, without explicit barriers each thread can see a different entirely copy of foo  from caches.

Say that your two threads ran at some point in time, then at some later point in time a third thread read foo, it could see a foo that was completely uninitialized, or the foo of either of the other two threads, or some mix of both, depending on what's happened with CPU memory caching.

My advice - don't try to be "smart" about concurrency, always try to be "safe".  Smart will bite you every time.  The [broken double-checked locking](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) article has some eye-opening insights into what can happen with memory access and instruction reordering in the absence of memory barriers (though specifically about Java and it's (changing) memory model, it's insightful for any language).

You have to be really on top of your language's specified memory model to shortcut barriers.  For example, Java allows a variable to be tagged volatile, which combined with a type which is documented as having atomic assignment, can allow unsynchronized assignment and fetch by forcing them through to main memory (so the thread is not observing/updating cached copies).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this safely and locklessly with a compare-and-swap operation.   What you've got *looks* thread safe but the compiler might create a writeback of the unchanged value under some circumstances, which will cause one thread to step on the other.

Also you're probably not getting as much performance as you think out of doing this, because having both threads writing to the same contiguous memory like this will cause a storm of [MESI transitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) inside the CPU's cache, each of which is quite slow. For more details on multithread memory coherence you can look at section 3.3.4 of Ulrich Drepper's "[What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/cpumemory.pdf)".

Comment: Yes, for such a simple for loop, doing it in two threads will probably go slower than doing it in just one because they are sharing data and (especially bad) writing to it. Hooray for negative scalability!

Answer (score 0):

If reads and writes to each array element are atomic (i.e. they're aligned properly with no word tearing as you mentioned), then there shouldn't be any problems in this code.  If `foo[i]` is less than either of `SOME_NUMBER` or `SOME_OTHER_NUMBER`, then at least one thread (possibly both) will set it to `MAGIC_VAL` at some point; otherwise, it will be untouched.  With atomic reads and writes, there are no other possibilities.

However, since your situation is more complicated, be very very careful -- make sure that `foo[i]` is truly only read once per loop and stored in a local variable.  If you read it more than once during the same iteration, you could get inconsistent results.  Even the slightest change you make to your code could immediately make it unsafe with race conditions, so comment heavily about the code with big red warning signs.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice, you should never be in the state where two threads are accessesing the same variable at the same time, regardless of the consequences. The example you give is over simplified, any majority complex samples will almost always have problems associated with it.. ...

Remember: **Semaphores** are your friend!

Answer (score 0):

That particular example is thread-safe.

There are no intermediate states really involved here.
That particular program would not get confused.

I would suggest a **Mutex** on the array, though.